# What is the correct sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, american-english, grammaticality-in-context, formal-language

> 1)Is there any way to check whether my letter has been received?
>
> 2)Is there any way to check whether my letter was received?
>
> 3)Is there any way to check if my letter was received?

I sent a letter a few moths ago. Now I want to ask them whether they received it or not.

Comment: HI, welcome to ELL! This is not the right place to get your homework done, so please edit your question so we can clarify your doubts.

Comment: I'd be happy to post an answer telling you what the correct sentence is, but there's not one. That's because they're all correct . So take your pick. Any one of those will work to ask what you want to ask. They're all grammatically correct and get the point across in such similar ways that any differences are negligible since whomever you ask will give the exact same answer regardless of which one you choose.